# Is this the correct way to gitignore files?

Tags: git

I'm doing an `i`nteractive `rebase` and trying to remove all `bin` and `obj` folders from my history. The folder structure of my repo is like

```
MyRepo
    MyClass
        .
        .
        bin
        obj
        .
    MyTestClass
        .
        .
        bin
        obj
        .
    .
    .
    .
```

I amended my first commit and added a `.gitignore` with contents

```
/MyClass/bin
/MyClass/obj
/MyTestClass/bin
/MyTestClass/obj
```

and put it in `MyRepo`.

However, when I go to commit I still see the files I don't want are there (`.exe`, `.pbd`, etc.)

Comment: So, you went to commit where the files were added in the first place and amended with only that change? Well.... you also have to rm the files (on the same amend action) so that they be gone moving forward. Replicate all the following revisions from the original branch with cherry-pick( ... or even with filter-branch) and then it would be like those files never existed on the branch.

Comment: @Edmundo Could you provide an outline of the series of commands to do this? I imagine I start with `git rebase -i --root`, then change the first commit to `edit` instead of `pick`, then once the rebase starts I do `git commit --ammend`, add the `.gitignore` file, run a `git rm` on the files that fall under the `gitignore`, then commit??

Comment: aaahhh... couldn't follow. Here's what I would do. First, set up two branches on the revision where the files were added and checkout the branch where things will be corrected: ```git branch fix-start <rev-id>; git checkout -b corrected-branch <rev-id>```. Now, modify the .gitignore file to have the right values (if it's not so already) and also delete the files that were "wrongly" added (can ```git rm --cache``` if you want to keep them on your working tree). Now ```git commit --amend --no-edit``` so you get a "clean corrected revision". More coming on next message

Comment: Now replicate all your changes as they were on the original branch: ```git cherry-pick fix-start..original-branch```. Now your branch should be clean and you can make the original branch now point to the current revision.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ignore files is using http://gitignore.io
The second is to understand that all the patterns that you put inside are to ignore files that are not committed (not tracked). Once that's done by error, `git rm --cached` is your friend.